# Вложенные джойны

Tags: postgresql, join

Есть таблица А с данными, есть таблица B, которая содержит имена настроек, есть таблицы C и D, которые хранят значения настроек. Нужно при выборке из таблицы А подтянуть значение настройки из таблицы C, либо из таблицы D (если в C нет).

Написал пока вот что:

```
select a.*, c.value as value
from a
left join c
    on a.id = c.a_id
    and c.setting_id in (select id from b 
        where b.type_id = a.type_id 
        and (b.code = 'Настройка для типа 1' or b.code = 'Настройка для типа 2'))
```

Но я не сообразил, как добавить таблицу D. Подозреваю, что нужно внутри джойна сделать ещё один джойн, в котором объединять значения из C и D.

Comment: Если предоставите пример таблиц с данными и желаемый результат, то ответ скорее всего будет более правильный. В текущем виде, сложно понять, что происходит сейчас и какой результат вы ожидаете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, вам надо использовать join. Только не вложенные, а идущие друг за другом - если объяснять по простому.

Плюс вы можете использовать функцию COALESCE(val1, val2) которая возвращает ненулевое значение.

Запрос будет примерно таким:

```
SELECT a.*, COALESCE(c.value, d.value) AS value
FROM a
LEFT JOIN c ON a.id = c.id_a
LEFT JOIN d ON a.id = d.id_a;
```

Тут делается выборка из таблицы **a** и делаются два LEFT JOIN к таблицам **c** и **d**. Если в таблице **c** нет записи, которая соответствует значению из таблицы **а**, то **c.value** будет равно NULL. В этом случае функция COALESCE вернет значение для **d.value**.

Думаю, что основной принцип понятен и у вас получится взять его за основу для решения вашей задачи.

А посмотреть как работает запрос и "поиграться" с ним можно [здесь](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/26KuCXQW2hWDS4bPJDyYvk/0)

Comment: Точно, про существование COALESCE я и забыл, спасибо.